# Reference or pointer: absolute value analogue of the variance

Tags: probability, reference-request

In the course of a project, I am looking at the following quantity, essentially an "absolute value analogue" of the variance for a random random variance (integrable) $X$:
$$
A[X] \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \mathbb{E}[\lvert X\rvert] - \lvert \mathbb{E}[X]\rvert
$$
which is non-negative due to the triangle inequality. (Note that is not the same as the absolute spread $\mathbb{E}[\lvert X - \mathbb{E}[X]\rvert]$.)

Has this quantity been considered in the literature? If so, where -- does it have a name, and have some of its properties (e.g., in term of conditional random variables, etc.) been investigated?

Comment: I don't know this quantity, but $A(X) = 2\min(E[X^+], E[X^-])$ with $X^+ = \max(X, 0)$ and $X^- = \max(-X,0)$.

Comment: @Gribouillis Thanks. Not sure I'll be using that fact, but that's good to keep in mind.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2414751/is-it-true-that-mathbbe-z-rvert-mathbbez-rvert-geq-mathbbe-math/2414794