# Is it true that $\mathbb{E}[| Z\rvert]+|\mathbb{E}[Z]\rvert\geq\mathbb{E}[|\mathbb{E}[Z\mid X]\rvert]+\mathbb{E}[|\mathbb{E}[Z\mid Y]\rvert]$?

Tags: probability, inequality, conditional-expectation

I have two (real-valued) independent random variables $X,Y$, and a function $f\colon \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Is it true that
$$
\mathbb{E}[\lvert f(X,Y) \rvert]+\lvert\mathbb{E}[ f(X,Y) ] \rvert \geq \mathbb{E}[\lvert \mathbb{E}[f(X,Y) \mid X]\rvert]+\mathbb{E}[\lvert \mathbb{E}[f(X,Y) \mid Y]\rvert] \tag{$\dagger$}
$$
? (If not, what is a counter-example?)

---

It looks eerily simple and intuitive, but at that point I wouldn't believe in my intuition, nor in eeriness in general. Note that if $f$ only depends on its first variable (for instance), i.e. if $f(X,Y) = g(X)$ for some function $g$, then setting $Z=g(X)$ we have
$$
\mathbb{E}[\lvert f(X,Y) \rvert]+\lvert\mathbb{E}[ f(X,Y) ] \rvert 
= \mathbb{E}[\lvert Z \rvert]+\lvert\mathbb{E}[ Z ] \rvert
$$ and
$$ 
\mathbb{E}[\lvert \mathbb{E}[f(X,Y) \mid X]\rvert]+\mathbb{E}[\lvert \mathbb{E}[f(X,Y) \mid Y]\rvert]=
\lvert \mathbb{E}[Z]\rvert+\mathbb{E}[\lvert Z\rvert]
$$
and we actually have equality in ($\dagger$). If $X,Y$ are two i.i.d. random variables, then ($\dagger$) seems to be equivalent to
$$
\mathbb{E}[\lvert X\rvert]^2 + \mathbb{E}[X]^2 \geq 2\mathbb{E}[\lvert X\rvert]\lvert\mathbb{E}[X]\rvert
$$
which again is true (this time from e.g. the AM-GM inequality).

Comment: Don't you want that $f$ is $\sigma(X,Y)$-measurable?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti True, I forgot to mention: $f$ has all the nice properties one can assume for things to be well-defined.

Comment: Mmh. Out of curiosity, what is the reason for the downvote? What can I do (or should have done) to improve my question?

Comment: I don't know, some votes cannot just be explained. I am voting up your question to balance it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality is not true in general; here is a counter example. If $X$ is uniformly distributed on $\{1,2\}$ and $Y$ is uniformly distributed over $\{-1,-2\}$. Then if $f(X,Y)=X+Y$:
$$
P(X+Y=-1)=P(X+Y=1)=\frac 14.
$$
We have:
$$
E[|f(X;Y)|]=\frac 12\\
E[f(X;Y)]=0\\
E[f(X;Y)|X]=X-\frac 32\in\{-\frac 12,\frac 12\}\\
E|E[f(X;Y)|X]|=E[\frac 12]=\frac 12\\
E[f(X;Y)|Y]=Y+\frac 32\in\{-\frac 12,\frac 12\}\\
E[|E[f(X;Y)|Y]|]=\frac 12.
$$

Comment: Interesting. Thank you!

Comment: A followup, wishful-thinking question: here, $f$ takes values in $\{-1,0,1\}$. If we have $f$ taking Boolean values, ie $f(x,y)\in\{-1,1\}$ for all $(x,y)$ (so that, in particular, the very first term, $\mathbb{E}[\lvert f(x,y)\rvert]$, is always $1$), is there a chance the inequality may hold?